# How to provide custom message in pytest-html-reporter

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html, pytest-html-reporter

Is there a way to provide custom message for each test when I use [pytest-html-reporter]https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html-reporter/?

I tried both print and logging statement for my tests but they are not shown in the report.

I call the pytest test as follows:

pytest --cache-clear -v -s --capture=tee-sys --html-report=./Reports/report.html --title='Dashboard' --self-contained-html .\DASHBOARD\Tests\test_dashboard.py

The report only shows the Suite,Test case name,Status,Time,Error Message.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have written a custom HTML that allowed me to add a note to the HTML.
The pytest-html-reporter have support for adding custom HTML so you could add a function that will do this with the extra fixtur:

Example:

```
def test_extras(extra):
     extra.append(
     {
        "name": "Text",
        "format": "text",
        "content": "<lorem ipsum> " * 100,
    })
```

Note this part of code is untested and just a quick example:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest
report_extras = []

@pytest.fixture
def extra():
    yield report_extras
    
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):

    global report_extras
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    report.extra = report_extras
```

Comment: Thank you. So this fixture must be placed inside conftest.py file? There are 100s of tests in the test suite and I want to provide custom message for all these. Is that feasible?

Comment: @Ram I updated the example provided, hopefully this will help you implementing it.
You can on top of this add a autouse fixture that can write the text you need for each report. Im sure there must be a nicer way if it is the same text per testcase or you could add it to the top section of the HTML.

Comment: Sorry, still no luck.
I have this in my test

    def test_001_login(self):
        """Login to UAT and click AGREE button in Site Minder"""
        if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
            pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
        print('Successfully clicked AGREE button in SiteMinder')
        self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
        self.loginPage.do_click_agree_button()
        time.sleep(2)
All I want is,whatever msg I have inside test fun visible in the html report.

Comment: @Ram I updated the example again, now tested and working. 
So in your case the "content" key you insert whatever message. For example `"content": "Successfully clicked AGREE button in SiteMinder",`

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be doing something, but still getting error. In my test functions, I've the "self" keyword (They are part of a class which I defined as class Test_Counterparty(unittest.TestCase)), so if I try def test_001_login(self, extra): by passing "extra" to my test function, I am getting "missing 1 required positional argument: 'extra'". In my conftest.py file, I exactly have what you've shown.

Comment: @Ram When using unittest you cannot use fixtures. So that's why it is not working. Do yourself a favor and get rid of it. Makes your life easier. Been there, done that.:
Read the bottom of docs(2th box in the bottom)
https://pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/unittest.html

Comment: Thank you. If I were to remove "unittest" from my class how would I do it?
class Test_Counterparty(unittest.TestCase)
If I get rid of "unittest.TestCase", none of my tests defined under def functions will work..
Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: ok. I got got rid of unittest from my class. It now looks like this. @pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class Test_Counterparty:

    def test_001_login(self, extra):
        extra.append(
            {
                "name": "Text",
                "format": "text",
                "content": "'Successfully clicked AGREE button in SiteMinder"
            }) However I still don't see the custom message in the html report. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am unsure why it does not work for you now.
Can you try the example i provided in your project and see if it works? If it does try adding the setup fixture you have and see if that causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this is what I have so far. My test function looks like this.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
request.cls.driver = driver
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get(TestData_common.Url)
yield
driver.quit()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class Test_Counterparty:
   def test_001_login(self, extra):
   extra.append(
        {
            "name": "Text",
            "format": "text",
            "content": "'Successfully clicked AGREE button"
        })
    if not TestData_common.URL_FOUND:
        pytest.skip(reason='Collateral UAT seems to be down...')
    print('Successfully clicked AGREE button')
    self.loginPage = LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.loginPage.do_click_agree_button()
    self.driver.maximize_window()
```

conftest.py looks like this.

```
import pytest
report_extras = []

@pytest.fixture
def extra():
   yield report_extras

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
   def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
   global report_extras
   outcome = yield
   report = outcome.get_result()
   extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
   report.extra = report_extras
```

Please note I am using https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html-reporter/ and not the default pytest html report. When I use the default pytest html report, all my custom messages are looking fine in the report.